# Filtrado multiple en un ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Tengo un método que recibe un Objeto de tipo `List` de una clase propia que se llama Pallet. La clase `Pallet` tiene una fecha de creación, un articulo, un id, un almacén...etc.
El método

> filterPalletWithDataretorna(List list, ListParametersFilter parameters);

retorna otra lista con los pallets que se han filtrado por los campos que he recibido en el objeto `ListParametersFilter`

```
public List<Pallet> filterPalletWithData(List<Pallet> list, ListParametersFilter parameters){
    //aqui va mi codigo de filtrado
         }
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es :

```
  public List<Pallet> filterPalletWithData(List<Pallet> list, ListParametersFilter parameters) {

            List<Pallet> returnedPalets = new ArrayList<>();

            returnedPalets.clear();
            //por ppc
            if (parameters.getId() >= 0)
                for (Pallet p : list) {
                    if (p.getIdNum() == parameters.getId())
                       returnedPalets.add(p);
                }


            if (parameters.getOrderNum() >= 0)
                for (Pallet p : list) {
                    if (p.getNum() == parameters.getOrderNum()) {
                          returnedPalets.add(p)
                    }
                }

......
}
```

Esta es la clase `ListParametersFilter`

```
 public class ListParametersFilter {

        private int id;
        private int orderNum;
        private long manufacturedArticle;
        private long plantation;
        private long crop;
        private long crew;
        private long customer;
        private long pallet;
        private long box;
        private String since;
        private String until;



        public ListParametersFilter(int id, int orderNum,
                                    long manufacturedArticle, long plantation,
                                    long crop, long crew, long customer, long pallet,
                                    long box, String since, String until) {
            this.id= id;
            this.orderNum = orderNum;
            this.manufacturedArticle = manufacturedArticle;
            this.plantation = plantation;
            this.crop = crop;
            this.crew = crew;
            this.customer = customer;
            this.pallet = pallet;
            this.box = box;
            this.since = since;
            this.until = until;
        }


        public ListParametersFilter(){}

    //Getters && setters
```

Esto va añadiendo los palets a una lista que luego devuelvo, solo me funciona si el campo de filtrado es único, por ejemplo por

> id

pero el problema viene cuando el filtrado es múltiple, es decir que pasa si el usuario quiere filtrar por

> almacén + id + articulo + fecha.

¿Como puedo implementar eso?

Comment: Podrías poner la implementación de `ListParametersFilter`?

Comment: Gracias @DavidDPG añadido

Comment: Sería posible cambiar la implementación de `ListParametersFilter`?

Comment: si , es perfectamente posible

Comment: Haz métodos privados cada uno para filtrar un posible campo y los vas llamando desde el método de filtrado publico, pasándole en cada caso el array resultando de la anterior llamada y el criterio concreto a filtrar en el método y finalmente devuelve el resultado.

Comment: la lista la pasas a un listview o similar? si la respuesta es asi, podrias cambiar el adaptador que viene por defecto y en el adaptador añadir el filterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Si no tienes Java 8

Si no tienes java 8, puedes crear una clase *filtradora* que tome la lista, aplique los filtros que quieras y te devuelva una copia de la lista filtrada.

He implementado una interfaz funcional (a la que no podrás pasarle una lambda) junto con una clase con genéricos que te permitirá aplicar varios filtros secuencialmente:

La interfaz:

```
public interface FilterPredicate<T>
{
    boolean applyFilter(T t);
}
```

La clase filtradora:

```
public class ListFilter<T>
{
    private List<T> list;
    
    public ListFilter(List<T> list)
    {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    }
    
    public void filter(FilterPredicate<T> filter)
    {
        Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            T t = iterator.next();
            if (!filter.applyFilter(t)) iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    
    public List<T> getList()
    {
        return this.list;
    }    
}
```

El truco está en sobreescribir el método `applyFilter` en el momento en el que llamas a `filter`, de tal manera que defines el método de filtrado en el momento de filtrar.
El proceso de filtrado va así:

```
// Una lista de Pallet de prueba
List<Pallet> palletList = new ArrayList<>();
palletList.add(new Pallet(1,5, "Toronto", "Primero"));
palletList.add(new Pallet(2, 45, "Madrid", "Segundo"));
palletList.add(new Pallet(3, 45, "Madrid", "Tercero"));
palletList.add(new Pallet(4, 46, "Madrid", "Cuarto"));

// Crear la clase filtradora de Pallet
ListFilter<Pallet> filterer = new ListFilter<>(palletList);

// Filtrar por todos los Pallet que tengan Madrid como warehouse
filterer.filter(new FilterPredicate<Pallet>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilter(Pallet pallet)
    {
        return pallet.getWarehouse().equals("Madrid");
    }
});

// De la lista resultante del primer filtro, filtrar los que tengan numero de orden = 45
filterer.filter(new FilterPredicate<Pallet>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilter(Pallet pallet)
    {
        return pallet.getNumOrder() == 45;
    }
});

// De la lista resultante del primer filtro, filtrar los que tengan id = 2
filterer.filter(new FilterPredicate<Pallet>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilter(Pallet pallet)
    {
        return pallet.getId() == 2;
    }
});
```

Como puedes ver, la cantidad de código es mucho mayor, aunque funciona.

## Si tienes Java 8

Si usas Java 8 y quieres añadir filtros de forma dinámica, se me ocurre que puedes hacer uso de la interfaz funcional [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) y su método [`and()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) para generar una lista de filtros dinámicamente.

Como `Predicate` es una [Interfaz Funcional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), puede ser objetivo de una expresión lambda, que en este caso será el filtro que quieras añadir.

En primer lugar, he cambiado tu clase `ListParametersFilter` para que represente una lista dinámica de filtros:

```
public class ListParametersFilter {
    
    List<Predicate<Pallet>> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void addFilter(Predicate<Pallet> filter)
    {
        filters.add(filter);
    }
    
    public Predicate<Pallet> getFilter()
    {
        return filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(p -> true);
    }
}
```

El método `addFilter` te permite colocar una expresión lambda (una función) como parámetro del método (porque acepta una interfaz funcional), que es justo lo que necesitas para añadir filtros. Un ejemplo de como usarlo:

```
ListParametersFilter filters = new ListParametersFilter();
filters.addFilter(pallet -> pallet.getId() == 5);
```

El método `getMultipleFilter` es el que te da todos los filtros en uno solo. El truco está en que el método `and()` de `Predicate` permite añadir otro `Predicate` mediante la operación lógica `&&`. (**Créditos a Marko Topolnik por enseñar cómo concatenar `Predicate` reduciendo un stream, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24554095/7023148) su respuesta en SO**).

He creado un pequeño ejemplo con una clase `Pallet` de prueba para demostrar el funcionamiento:

```
public void testFiltrado()
{
    List<Pallet> pallets = new ArrayList<>();
    pallets.add(new Pallet(4, "No cumple ningun filtros", 3));
    pallets.add(new Pallet(5, "Cumple el primer filtro", 4));
    pallets.add(new Pallet(5, "Cumple ambos filtros", 5));
    
    ListParametersFilter filters = new ListParametersFilter();
    filters.addFilter(pallet -> pallet.getId() == 5);
    System.out.println("Filtro: id = 5 aplicado");
    
    pallets.stream().filter(filters.getMultipleFilter()).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getAlmacen()));
    
    filters.addFilter(pallet -> pallet.getOrderNum() == 5);
    System.out.println("Filtro: orderNum = 5 aplicado");
    
    pallets.stream().filter(filters.getMultipleFilter()).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getAlmacen()));
}
```

Y la salida:

```
Filtro: id = 5 aplicado
Cumple el primer filtro
Cumple ambos filtros
Filtro: orderNum = 5 aplicado
Cumple ambos filtros
```

Para devolver una lista, simplemente cambia la operación terminal `forEach` por `collect` :

```
return pallets.stream().filter(filters.getMultipleFilter()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: tiene una pinta estupenda pero no uso java 8 :(

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta añadiendo un apartado para no java 8, pero sin java 8 creo que no puedes añadir filtros de forma dinámica

Comment: genial!! gracias