# Duda en API stream, filter , funciones flecha

Tags: java

Buenas tardes comunidad soy nuevo en java 8 y tengo una par de dudas a la hora de desarrollar mi código utilizando la API stream y funciones flecha, el código es el siguiente

```
List<Account> listAccounts = myList
if(fiterName.compareTo("")!=0){
      ListAccounts = ip.stream().filter(x -> filterName.equals(x.getNombre()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Con este código aplico un filtro por Nombre a las lista de tipo Account mi duda viene a partir de aplicar varios filtros es decir ademas de filterName puedo tener filterType, filterModal, filterStatus ...

La solución mas rápida que encuentro es a cada filter pasar la lista por un nuevo stream "Pero según yo esto seria la peor opción ya que pienso que estaría iterando un vez por cada filter y  no seria lo correcto" (tomen en cuenta que si el filter es "" no hace falta hacer nada)

Ahora la solución que yo veo que es mejor es meter el if dentro de la funcion flecha y aplicar varias condiciones dentro del statement de la función de esta forma

```
  List<Account> ListAccounts = ip.stream()
                 .filter(x -> {
                       if (fiterName.compareTo("")!=0){
                             filterName.equals(x.getNombre())
                       }
                       if (fiterType.compareTo("")!=0){
                             filterType.equals(x.getType())
                       }
                       \\ Y de esta forma un statement de if por cada condicion
                       else{}
                  })
                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Las preguntas son:

Esta forma es la mas optima de hacerlo?, como le digo a la funcion flecha que en caso de que no entre a ningún if no haga nada? (me marcaba como necesario el else),hay una mejor solución para hacerlo? tomando en cuenta que los filters pueden llegar vacíos y entonces no se tendría que hacer nada pero tambien pueden tener valor y se deben aplicar todos al mismo tiempo

Comment: Podrías hacer un `Predicate` para cada condición, y otro Predicate que cumpla cada `Predicate` de los anteriores, y le pasas ese último Predicate al filter por ejemplo. También podrías hacer un método para ello y luego pasarselo como un método referenciado a través del filter.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Filtrado multiple en un ArrayList](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106835/filtrado-multiple-en-un-arraylist). Echale un ojo a esa pregunta, creo que la respuesta puede serte de ayuda.

Comment: Agrega tu clase account para poder ayudarte, por favor