# ¿Filtro con múltiples condiciones?

Tags: android, kotlin

Es posible, en kotlin, utilizar el método .filter en una lista y que dentro del cuerpo del filtro se pueda usar una doble condición?
Por ejemplo:

`numberList.filter { n -> n > 5}`

Esto me devolverá una lista con todos los números mayores a 5 dentro de la lista original, pero yo quiero algo como:

`numberList.filter { n -> (n > 5 && n < 20)}`

esto no se puede hacer actualmente con .filter pero habrá alguna forma similar?

Se que se puede hacer de esta forma:

`numberList.filter { n -> (n > 5)}.filter { n -> (n < 20)}`

Pero para el caso real que lo quiero utilizar necesito aplicar muchas condiciones y no seria lo optimo llenar de .filter el codigo

Comment: Tanto `Iterable#filter` como `Sequence#filter` aceptan únicamente una función con la firma `(T) -> Boolean`. Lo que sí que puedes hacer es una clase a la que puedas añadir varias funciones de filtro y combinarlas todas. Respondí una pregunta similar [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106879/57827). Cuando tenga tiempo responderé a esta en kotlin.

Comment: Y si pones dos filters y en cada uno le agregas tu validación?

Comment: @rguzman Hay que tener cuidado: si se ponen dos filters a un iterable en kotlin, se iterará dos veces la colección.  Para tener un comportamiento *lazy* hay que cambiarlo a una secuencia con `.toSequence()`

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que este códgio numberList.filter { n -> (n > 5 && n < 20)} no es valido? Es totalmente valido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como `filter` acepta cualquier función con firma `(T) -> Boolean`, puedes poner cualquier función que la cumpla y se adapte a las necesidades que tienes. Tomando como ejemplo una lista de enteros:

```
// Lista de prueba
val stub = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
```

Puedes definir una batería de funciones de filtrado que cumplan con la susodicha firma:

```
// Siempre devolvera true y ningun elemento sera eliminado de la lista
fun alwaysTrue(number: Int) = true

// Solo dara true para elementos pares, por lo que los impares se quedan fuera
fun onlyEven(number: Int) = number % 2 == 0

// Para un rango especifico
fun inRange(number: Int, range: IntRange) = range.contains(number)

// Una comprobacion mas compleja
fun complexCriteria(number: Int): Boolean = when {
    number % 2 != 0 -> false
    number in 5..20 -> false
    else -> number.isPrime() 
    // añadir los casos que necesites
}
```

Y usarlas todas de una manera casi intercambiable:

```
// Su uso es similar:
val noChanges = stub.filter { alwaysTrue(it) }

val evenNumbers = stub.filter { onlyEven(it) }

val inSpecificRange = stub.filter { inRange(it, 5..20) } // esta se ajusta a tu ejemplo

val withComplexCriteria = stub.filter { complexCriteria(it) }
```

Comment: Los ejemplos que agregaste no eran exactamente lo que necesitaba pero aclararme que se puede agregar cualquier tipo de función que retorne Boolean me ayudo, Gracias

Comment: @NicolasSobarzo me alegro de que te sirviera de ayuda, no obstante recuerda que no es *cualquier función que retorne Boolean*, es **cualquier función que tome como parámetro un valor del tipo que contiene tu iterable y retorne Boolean**.